# Using Client-Side GWT to Retrieve GData Contacts While Hosted on AppEngine

Tags: gwt, gdata-api

I've been trying to do this since July, and have been unsuccessful every attempt I use. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**What I Need:** I'm hosting an Internet Application on AppEngine, and I need to pull the contacts feed for a user.

**What I've Tried:**

1. gwt-gdata: A nice library I tried to use, but for some reason I could only seem to get it to work while testing locally in an eclipse test environment. Once it was uploaded to AppEngine I would get a javascript exception that was difficult to diagnose. Seeing as how I could pull contacts while testing it locally in eclipse's test environment, I assumed it had to do with a restriction on AppEngine.
2. gdata-api: I tried using http GET requests to try and get the feed, but it seemed that all my requests returned blank (Didn't even have errors). I assumed that somehow AppEngine was blocking requests like this somehow. I have no idea if this is correct.
3. GData on the Server: After working OAuth out, I was able to get everything working with this approach, but for a user to load all of their contacts to the application, it uses the server for a full 6 seconds per request, which is unacceptable.
4. GData Javascript Library with GWT JSNI: I'm getting an error that seems to be a similar error to what I was getting when I tried gwt-gdata. I was a bit more proficient with diagnosing the Javascript error this time and it seems that the javascript library isn't loading properly. I tried several different ways of loading it, without any luck.

**Current Situation:** So now I'm back to square one, trying to use only the clients resources to retrieve contacts while being hosted on AppEngine. Does AppEngine actually have restrictions in place to somehow limit what I'm trying to do, or have I just failed to do these things correctly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1 looks the best - although this library hasn't had ny work on it for a year and a half, which makes me wonder if it has been abandoned by google - does anyone know any better?

Since the client-side stuff from your AppEngine project is implemented as pure javascript and run at the client it's difficult to see ho AppEngine could be getting in the way. What happens if you remove any server-side stuff from your project (leaving only the bit getting the feed of contacts - perhaps you can hard code the auth token temporarily?), compile the project and deploy that on a simple apache server?